# How to free memory if a TabItem is removed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, memory, tabcontrol

[image]

Who runs the app below will note:

- Window has appeared ==> memory usage is 19.3 MB
- Select "Tab B" ==> memory usage is rising to 40.3 MB
- Click Button "Action" to remove "Tab B" ==> memory usage is
  decreasing to 39.4 MB

**Question:** How can I shrink back memory consumption to 19.3 MB?

App code `Xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        FontSize="14"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="230"
        Width="530"
        Visibility="Visible"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Name="tabControl" Grid.Row="0">
            <TabItem Name="tabItem_1" Header="--- Tab A ---" />
            <TabItem Name="tabItem_2" Header="--- Tab B ---">
                <RichTextBox Name="rtb"
                             IsDocumentEnabled="True"
                             VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
                             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                             IsReadOnly="False"
                             AcceptsTab="True"
                             Margin="5,5,5,5"
                             Padding="5,5,5,5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,10,10">
            <Button Name="buttonAction" Content="   _Action   " Click="buttonAction_Click" />
            <Button Name="buttonCancel" Content="   _Cancel   " Click="buttonCancel_Click" IsCancel="True" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

App code `C#`:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnLoad.
        /// </summary>
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6000; i++)
            {
                Run run = new Run("»Today is the day before tomorrow.« – »Are you sure, Mr President?« ");
                Bold bold = new Bold(run);
                Paragraph para = new Paragraph(bold);

                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    para.Background = Brushes.SandyBrown;
                else
                    para.Background = Brushes.Khaki;

                rtb.Document.Blocks.Add(para);
            }

            rtb.Document.Blocks.Remove(rtb.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock);
            tabItem_1.Focus();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Button "Action".
        /// </summary>
        private void buttonAction_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl.Items.RemoveAt(1);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Button "Cancel".
        /// </summary>
        private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET (and in general, most garbage collected environments) do not deterministically free up memory when an object is not used anymore. It marks the items as eligible for collection and will free them up when it sees fit (there are algorithms in the garbage collector that take into account many things: memory pressure on the system, whether you are doing other processes that might be affected by the slowdown when collecting, etc.)

You can "semi"-force a garbage collection by calling `GC.Collect()`, but the general consensus is that you should **not** do it unless there are good reasons to. The algorithms that determine whether the memory is needed and how aggresive the collection must be are made by very smart people that usually know better than you :-)

If you have memory problems (having memory problems means you run out of memory on the system, not that your process is using more memory than you -think- it should), then it's time to find "leaks", or otherwise unneeded object references that are preventing the garbage collector to do its job... but if you don't have those problems, the memory occuppied by the process in the Task Manager is not enough reason to think it's not working as it should.

Furthermore, the .NET CLR reserves memory on the native heap to make managed allocation and deallocation faster (that's basically what the task manager is showing you, how much memory is allocated by the CLR for your process), this is what is called the "managed heap". So even if the garbage collector actually frees up your control, in general and unless there's a reason not-to, it'll keep some of that memory reserved for your process so that if you need to create other managed objects, it'll put those objects in that reserved memory: again, unless there's a reason not to have that reserved memory (like: the system is running out of memory, for example), the fact that you see it allocated on the Task Manager is irrelevant and does not mean it's not doing its job.

More basic literature to the respect:

- [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Automatic Memory Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t(v=vs.110).aspx)